# Known IE 8 PHP Session issue?

Tags: php, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a login system that is being authenticated via a php session. My client is saying that login is failing now that I have moved the site to a new server. But only when he uses IE 8. I have been unable to replicate these issues.

What makes it even more odd is that it all works on the previous host. I am at a loss to whether it is a browser issue, the server change or anything else.

Are there any know issues? I thought it may be a header("location: ") issue, but it seemingly is working on the previous host.

Any help appreciated

The login code is this (It keeps returning my client to index.php?invalid even though he says he is entering the correct login details and I am able to access with no problem.

```
<?php
require('includes/functions.php');
require('includes/db.php');

$user=clean($_POST[user]);
$pass=clean($_POST[pass]);

$qry="SELECT id FROM table WHERE userfield='$user' 
AND passwordfield='".md5($pass)."'";

$result=mysql_query($qry);

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
    //Login Successful
    //Regenerate session ID to
    //prevent session fixation attacks
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id();
    $result=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $_SESSION['USER']=$result['id'];
    //Write session to disc
    session_write_close();
    header("location: success.php");
    exit();
}
    header("location: index.php?invalid");
?>
```

Comment: Not enough detail, impossible to tell what's wrong. Is the session cookie working? Is its settings correct? Does IE8's protection mechanisms for some reason think your server is a malware host? Blah blah blah...

Comment: If you are unable to replicate the issue in IE8, then there is no issue. Tell your client to be more specific or send you some screenshots.

Comment: its a browser issue I used to have it, but there is a work around that. Can you post your login code?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Your right more information is key. I have been tackling this most of the day and I just got to the point of crying help when posting this and didnt take the time i should have. Give me a sec I will edit

Comment: @Grigor does this help or would you like anything else? What was your work around. Cheers

Comment: start_session(); must be declared before any of your code usually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, IE8 has this problem with session cookies, especially when redirects are used. Try putting `session_set_cookie_params(0);` prior to starting the session - this would ensure that the session cookie will not expire until the browser is closed.