# Session vars and IE8

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to set session variables with PHP, which is used to set a selection box value that is pre loaded in PHP. My code, for the session, is:

```
session_start();

echo "test";
echo $_SESSION['accountMain']; //For session test

if(isset($_POST["accountMain"]))
{
    $account = $_POST["accountMain"];
    $_SESSION['accountMain'] = $account;
    session_write_close();
}
else if(isset($_SESSION['accountMain']))
     {
        $account = $_SESSION['accountMain'];
     }
     else
     {
        $account = "AMX";
     }
```

On Chrome and Firefox all is good, I can see `$_SESSION['accountMain']` being printed and the selection box is being setted by the session variable. But on IE8, the session var isn't getting printed.

I've looked all over the web sphere, found some info about it, and based on it made these changes:

First, I've changed my webpages file names and removed `_` from it, as I read it makes problems with IE8 and sessions.

Second, I've added this to my code:

```
<?php
header('P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR CURa ADMa OUR IND PHY ONL COM STA"');
?>
```

I've also added the `session_write_close();`

In my IE8 security setting i'I've un checked the *Enabled Protected Mode* for all of the zones and on the *Privacy setting* I set to always allow session cookies and accept cookies from all sources.

But still, the session variable doesn't get printed.

What do I miss ?

Comment: I think you should try this and check your browsers **echo 'Testing '.$_SESSION['accountMain'];**

Comment: Check if this helps you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209257/known-ie-8-php-session-issue

Comment: @TasosBitsios Thanks, but it also didn't help :(

Comment: inspect your cookies somehow... a javascript snippet like `alert(document.cookie);` will do if you have no debugging tools

Comment: @TasosBitsios I get nothing on IE8. On Chrom I do get a `PHPSESSID`.

Answer (score 0):

You need check if you have cookies enabled in IE8.

Comment: Is there some another check that wasn't mentioned in my question ?